# Using the Facebook 'like' button on a responsive page

Tags: html, css, facebook, responsive-design

I have a request to include social media buttons on a responsive site.  This doesn't seem so difficult at first except I noticed that the Facebook 'like' button is an iframe so obviously can't be made responsive.  I've been searching for ways to include it but I haven't had much luck.

Has anyone come across a solution, or better yet, a new responsive friendly version of the button that I haven't found?  This problem got me to wondering does the Facebook 'like' button even belong on mobile?

Comment: You could make your own button, do you have knowledge of php or some back-end language?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the button is in an iframe does not affect anything. You can always put it in a div and style the div accordingly.

```
<div class="facebook-button">
   <!-- Facebook button code goes here -->
</div>

.facebook-button {
    ... responsive css here ...
}
```